# Differernce between <meta content=' ' name=' '> and <meta name=' ' content=' '>

Tags: html

Is there any difference between

```
  <meta content="medical transcription company, medical transcriptions, medical transcription services, US based company" name="keywords">
```

and

```
  <meta name="keywords" content="medical transcription company, medical transcriptions, medical transcription services, US based company">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no functional difference.  Element attributes can appear in any order.